# upgrading cordova fails (Node 6.9.1 , OSX El Capitan)

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic-framework

Upgrading Ionic from CLI 1.7.16 to 2.X finished successfully but it asks for Cordova to be upgraded too. All my attempts to upgrade cordova fail: "npn install -g cordova" fails with error in a package called "abbrev" . See screenshot below.

I am on newest Node (v6.9.1 as recommended by Ionic, npm v3.10.8), Mac OSX El Capitan with 16GB of ram.

Any ideas what may be wrong and how to overcome that?

Thanks much !!

Zvi

[image: screenshot]

Comment: there is another relevant error message just before that: "Error: Cannot find module 'os-tmpdir'"

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. It was a conflict with an older version of cordova that didn't get removed in the installation process. Removing it manually, then installing cordova, solved the problem.